# How to solve error (Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, error-handling

here is my code i face error when i post the file the error generated is header can not set after sent to the client.the error code is 500 internal server error.it gives me the error message but the error can't handle the error & code is given below.
GET /user1/adduser 500 479.059 ms - 48
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './public/images/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    })
    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
        if (
            file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
            file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
            file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"){
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(new Error("file formate should be a png,jpg,jpeg"),false);//here error generated but my server breaks down.(500 internal server Error).
        }
    };
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        limits: {
            fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024  //2 mb size of file .
        }, fileFilter:fileFilter
    }).single('logo_path');

router.post('/adduser', upload, (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: ``//here my auth server URL
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
        else {
            let result = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(result.success);
            if (result.success) {
               // res.send("Email ID already Exists: ");
            } else {
           //user.add user consists my sql query (model)
                user.addUser(req.body, req.file.filename,(err, rows) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                        //console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.status(201).send("data inserted succesfully");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are trying to send response multiple times for a single request to the client, that's why you are getting this error

Comment: try to add `return` when you want to send response to the frontEnd. Show it's well looks like: `return res.send('Some text')`